# How to convert a list with different length element to a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Here I meet so often this kind of problem when I have a loop. The first one is solved.

[1] I have a list like this:

```
myList <- list(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 5, 6, 7), c= c(9,10))
```

now I want to convert the list to a data.frame like this:

```
    Value
a   1, 2, 3
b   4, 5, 6, 7
c   9, 10
```

Does anyone show me a general function by basic R?

[2]New problem arising:

```
mynewList <- list(a = c(1, 2, 3, "f"), b = c(4, 5, 6), c= c(9,10), d=list(1,2))
```

I want to convert the mynewlist to a dataframe like this:

```
    a   b   c   d 
1   1   4   9  1
2   2   5  10  2
3   3   6  na  na
4   f   na na  na
```

I use the below command before, it works without the d element. but it didnot work for now.

```
df<-data.frame(lapply(myList, "length<-" , max(lengths(myList))))
```

Does anyone show me a general function by basic R?

Comment: The approach you've used for question 2 is correct. The issue is how you've written the entry for `d`: you need to add `d` as `d=list(c(1, 2))`. Writing it as `d = list(1, 2)` spreads `d` over two elements in the final list, as can be seen if you look at `mynewList` before trying to put it into a data.frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. We can use `sapply` and `paste`:

```
df <- data.frame(Value = sapply(myList, paste, collapse = ','))
```

**Output:**

```
    Value
a   1,2,3
b 4,5,6,7
c    9,10
```

### 2. We can `unlist` each list element before applying max lengths:

```
df <- data.frame(lapply(mynewList, function(x) {
  x <- unlist(x)
  length(x) <- max(lengths(mynewList))
  return(x)
}))
```

**Output:**

```
  a  b  c  d
1 1  4  9  1
2 2  5 10  2
3 3  6 NA NA
4 f NA NA NA
```

Comment: Do you know how to solve my new question? @avid_useR

Answer (score 0):

This approach keeps your `Value` as a list:

```
myDF <- data.frame(t(rbind(myList)))

myDF
#      myList
#a    1, 2, 3
#b 4, 5, 6, 7
#c      9, 10

str(myDF)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ myList:List of 3
#  ..$ a: num  1 2 3
#  ..$ b: num  4 5 6 7
#  ..$ c: num  9 10
```

Comment: thanks a lot. nice one. this method didn't change the type of each element.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the updated request, I had a similar problem, with binding together columns of different lengths.
I solved by writing a wrap of `cbind` that also add `NA` values.

```
cbind.NA <- function (...) {
   myDFs <- list(...)
   myDFs <- lapply(myDFs, as.matrix)
   n <- max(sapply(myDFs, nrow)) 
   do.call(cbind, lapply(myDFs, function(x) rbind(x, matrix(,n-nrow(x), ncol(x)))))
}
```

Because you have `rows` and a list, you need to use `rbind` and convert the element of your list to `data.frame` before binding them together.

```
newDF <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(myList)){
   tmp <- as.data.frame(myList[[i]])
   names(tmp) <- names(myList[i])
   newDF <- cbind.NA(newDF,tmp) 
}

newDF
      a b  c
[1,]  1 4  9
[2,]  2 5 10
[3,]  3 6 NA
[4,] NA 7 NA

t(newDF)
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
a    1    2    3   NA
b    4    5    6    7
c    9   10   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution I can conjure up using base R.

```
cbindlist = function(list_obj){

  lengths = unlist(lapply(list_obj, length))
  NA_lengths = sapply(lengths, function(x) max(lengths) - x)
  cols = names(list_obj)

  out = data.frame(sapply(1:length(list_obj), function(x) c(list_obj[[x]], rep(NA, NA_lengths[x]))))
  colnames(out) = cols

  return(out)
}
```

It works for both of your examples:

```
lista = list(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 5, 6, 7), c = c(9,10))
newlista = list(a = c(1, 2, 3, "f"), b = c(4, 5, 6), c= c(9,10), d=list(1,2))

> cbindlist(lista)
   a b  c
1  1 4  9
2  2 5 10
3  3 6 NA
4 NA 7 NA

> cbindlist(newlista)
  a  b  c  d
1 1  4  9  1
2 2  5 10  2
3 3  6 NA NA
4 f NA NA NA
```

Comment: thank you very much. this way is very clear, and importantly, quite suitable for me, a R beginner.