# Read multiple csv files (and skip 2 columns in each csv file) into one dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I have a folder of about 100 csv files and I want to read them into one dataframe in R. I kind of know how to do this but I have to skip the first two columns in every csv file and that is the part I am stuck on.
My code so far is:

```
myfiles <- list.files(pattern = ".csv") # create a list of all csv files in the directory
data_csv <- ldply(myfiles, read.csv)
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: I would use a `for` loop and `rbind` only the columns you need. There are countless of post that explain how to do something similar. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57909672/convert-separate-df-in-a-folder-into-a-single-df-in-r/57910748#57910748 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58070431/how-to-convert-a-list-with-different-length-element-to-a-dataframe/58082615#58082615 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `data.table` package functions `fread()` and `rbindlist()` will provide the result you're after faster than any of the other `base` or `tidyverse` alternatives.

```
library(data.table)

## Create a list of the files
FileList <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")

## Pre-allocate a list to store all of the results of reading
## so that we aren't re-copying the list for each iteration
DTList <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(FileList))

## Read in all the files, excluding the first two columns
for(i %in% seq_along(DTList)) {
  DTList[[i]] <- data.table::fread(FileList[[i]], drop = c(1,2))
}

## Combine the results into a single data.table
DT <- data.table::rbindlist(DTList)

## Optionally, convert the data.table to a data.frame to match requested result
## Though I would recommend looking into using data.table instead!
data.table::setDF(DT)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way using purrr. You could do basically the same syntax with the base lapply function. The `map_dfr` function used below applies the `read.csv` or `fread` using vectorization. It also has a nice feature of simultaneously binding the dataframes (by row) together to give you a single dataframe.

```
library(purrr)
myfiles <- list.files(pattern = ".csv") # create a list of all csv files in the directory
data_csv <- map_dfr(myfiles, ~read.csv(.x)[,-c(1,2)])
```

And taking a note from Matt's answer, you can go even faster with `fread` and vectorization:

```
myfiles <- list.files(pattern = ".csv") # create a list of all csv files in the directory
data_csv <- map_dfr(myfiles, ~data.table::fread(.x, drop = c(1,2))
```

And if you want to go *really* fast, you could always parallelize with the `furrr` package.

```
library(purrr)
library(furrr)

# sets up the workers
plan("multisession")

myfiles <- list.files(pattern = ".csv") # create a list of all csv files in the directory
data_csv <- future_map_dfr(myfiles, ~data.table::fread(.x, drop = c(1,2))
```